# SharePoint or IIS in general passing Windows Authentication to IFrame calling another site on the same server and domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, iframe, sharepoint, windows-authentication

I have a SharePoint site that is running Windows Authentication (NTLM).
We have a web part that has an IFrame in it that points to another web page that also uses Windows Authentication (NTLM).
Both SharePoint and the WebApplication are located on the same machine on IIS running under the same app pool on the same domain using the same SSL cert and the same machine key.

**Example**
We have SP1.test.com (SharePoint Site) and NET1.test.com (.net web application)
Both running Windows Authentication only (all other auths have been disabled) with NTLM as the provider.
They both have the same Machine Key.

Here is the web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
    <forms name=".TESTAUTH" cookieless="AutoDetect" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" timeout="600" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain="*.test.com" />
</authentication>
<machineKey validationKey="1234" decryptionKey="1234" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

How do we get this to work without the site requiring double authentication?

**NOTE**
Both of these sites are accessed internally and externally.

Comment: You have to look at option enabling SSO (Single Sign On). If Windows Authentication enabled & if the user device in same domain and authenticated we can pass the credentials by enabling settings in IE options.

Comment: @Suresh This would only work if the users are using IE and if their devices are within the domain. I was hoping to make this work seamless like Forms Authentication does between two different sites sharing the auth cookie.

Comment: Then you have to look at enabling SSO. AFAIK this will work. Check how you can setup and establish CAS for Single Sign On.

Comment: @Suresh We are not looking to create an Enterprise SSO. It seems that IIS can do this with ease when using Forms Authentication. Not sure why it does not work as easy with Windows Authentication. I was hoping it was just a setting or config changes.